# Making a high number of http GET requests with few threads using Netty

Tags: java, http, netty, multiplexing

Unfortunately, JDK's HttpUrlConnection or UrlConnection do not run asynchronously. So, if HTTP connections hang for any reason, you will end up loosing a thread. Plus, Selector's multiplexing allows for using only a few threads for making a high number of HTTP GET calls. 
So, I have been developing a code that uses NIO's Selector and makes HTTP GET. So, the core works well except that to fully support HTTP 1.1, I have to support Keep-Alive, chunked-transfer-mode, and several other things that HTTP 1.1 supports.

So, I have been also looking to do this with Netty, but I have not been able to find an example, which shows how to make several HTTP GET requests using a single thread.

So, I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a netty example or any other appropriate library.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Netty's Channel EventLoop model manage a minimum number of threads to support a maximum number of client connections.  It is baked into the framework.

There are a few HTTP examples in the API Docs (there is a folder called example in the source files).  There are also a few HTTP examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action) based on the examples from the Manning book [Netty in Action](http://www.manning.com/maurer/). Chapter 15 - EventLoop and Thread-Model of this book discusses all this in detail.

Comment: Thank you for this great tip. I will start taking a look at the Channel EventLoop.